# Adding Twitter Feeds on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, site, third-party-software, twitter

I want display my twitter feeds in the Home Page of my intranet site. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter provides rich devloper API's. You can check that here and create your own. Else you can use the one twitter provides. Something like

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
href="https://twitter.com/twitterdev"
data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE">
Tweets by @twitterdev
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Comment: Nice! thanks @Amal I will try it out then give you the results. Question is, do I add it to the page layout code?

Comment: after putting the script and clicking on the home page, it disappears. Why?

Comment: Did you saved the page and published/approved it?

Comment: What I did was to add a text file into the assets folder (twitter.txt), secondly I added a Content Editor into the Home Page and linked it. It worked!

Comment: Thanks,. but how to retrieve tweets from multiple twitter accounts ?

Answer (score 3):

You can download few of the existing FREE Twitter Web Parts

[Free Sharepoint Twitter Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5794)

[Search for Twitter Feed](https://webpartgallery.codeplex.com/)

[Twitter Web Part](https://www.apptha.com/category/extension/Others/sharepoint-twitter-webpart)

Comment: I would go with the third one because of how valid it seems to work but the issue is, it's complex.